# Error undefined variable and some data insert into database but not all data

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

Here is the error

> Notice: Undefined variable: domain in
>   C:\wamp64\www\email_verify\index.php on line 59
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: target in C:\wamp64\www\email_verify\index.php on line 59
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: target_ip in C:\wamp64\www\email_verify\index.php on line 59

the code is

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_POST["email_verify_btn"])) {

        $email = $_POST["email_verify"];

        if(strpos($email,"\n")) {

        $text = explode("\n",$email);



        }
            function domain_exists($text)
            {
                $domain = substr(strrchr($text, "@"), 1);

                $arr = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);                

                if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {
                    return $arr[0]['target'];
                }
            }

            foreach ($text as $abc) {


                    if(domain_exists($abc)){
                        $domain = substr(strrchr($fetch_email, "@"), 1);

                        $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);

                            if($data) {
                            $status = "email id is valid";                      
                        }

                        if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {

                            foreach ($data as $key1) {

                                $host = $key1['host'];
                                $target = $key1['target'];
                                $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);

                            }

                        }



                    } else {
                      $status = "mx recored not exist";
                    }

                    $c_by = 1;
                    $c_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $c_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                    $insert = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `email_verify_list`(`primary_email`,`host_name`,`target`,`target_ip`,`session`,`status`,`created_by`, `created_date`, `created_ip`) VALUES ('$abc','$domain','$target','$target_ip','$c_ip','$status','$c_by','$c_date','$c_ip')");

                    if($insert) {
                        $_SESSION['date_time'] = $c_date;
                        echo "<script>alert('successfully');</script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<script>alert('!!!!!not successfully');</script>";                                    
                    }                   
            }                               









}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>BULK EMAIL VARIFIER</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="pages/ico/60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="pages/ico/76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="pages/ico/120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="pages/ico/152.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<meta content="" name="description"/>
<meta content="" name="author"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/switchery/css/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="pages/css/pages-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="main-stylesheet" href="pages/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link href="assets/plugins/codrops-dialogFx/dialog.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="fixed-header ">

<div id="rootwizard" class="m-t-50">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-linetriangle nav-tabs-separator nav-stack-sm">
<li class="active">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1"><span>EMAIL VERIFY</span></a>
</li>
</ul>

<form  method="post" action="" > 

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane padding-20 active slide-left" id="tab1">
<div class="row row-same-height">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="padding-30">
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">ENTER YOUR EMAIL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></font></label><br>
        <textarea cols="43" rows="9" name="email_verify"  style="border-color:white;border-width:thin;padding:4pt;" multiple/></textarea><br>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" name="email_verify_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info"  style="padding:11pt;width:200px;"/><span><b><font size="2">SUBMIT</font></b></span></button>
        </div>
        </div>  <br><br>
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <table width="100%" class="table ">
        <tr class="success">
        <th>PRIMARY EMAIL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></th>
        <th>HOST NAME</th>
        <th>TARGET</th>
        <th>TARGET IP</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 

        $select = $connect->query("SELECT * from `email_verify_list` where session='".$_SESSION['date_time']."' order by id");
        while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['primary_email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['host_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['target']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['target_ip']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

</div>



<script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-easy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-bez/jquery.bez.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ios-list/jquery.ioslist.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-actual/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/classie/classie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/switchery/js/switchery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap3-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-autonumeric/autoNumeric.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-form-wizard/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/summernote/js/summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="pages/js/pages.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/form_wizard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
         window.intercomSettings = {
           app_id: "xt5z6ibr"
         };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i solve it please send me updated code for this

Comment: any one help me for this.....??

Comment: what do you want to return from the domain_exists function?

Comment: i want to multiple email verify from textarea so i use foreach loop and verify it by domain exist

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_POST["email_verify_btn"])) {
   $email = $_POST["email_verify"];
   if(strpos($email,"\n")) {
   $text = explode("\n",$email);
}
function domain_exists($text)
{
    $domain = substr(strrchr($text, "@"), 1);
    $arr = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);                   
    if ($arr[0]['host'] == $domain && !empty($arr[0]['target'])) {                        
       return $arr[0]['target'];
    }
}

foreach ($text as $abc) {
  $domain = "";
  $target = "";
  $target_ip = "";
  if(domain_exists($abc)){
        $domain = substr(strrchr($fetch_email, "@"), 1);
        $data = @dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
        if($data) {
           $status = "email id is valid";                      
        }
        if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
           foreach ($data as $key1) {
              $host = $key1['host'];
              $target = $key1['target'];
              $target_ip = gethostbyname($key1['target']);
           }
        }
   } else {
        $status = "mx recored not exist";
   }
   $c_by = 1;
   $c_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $c_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $insert = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `email_verify_list`(`primary_email`,`host_name`,`target`,`target_ip`,`session`,`status`,`created_by`, `created_date`, `created_ip`) VALUES ('$abc','$domain','$target','$target_ip','$c_ip','$status','$c_by','$c_date','$c_ip')");
      if($insert) {
         $_SESSION['date_time'] = $c_date;
         echo "<script>alert('successfully');</script>";
      } else {
         echo "<script>alert('!!!!!not successfully');</script>";                                    
      }                   
   }
}
?>
```

Variable's was undefined because they are out of scope. if you want to use them than you should declare them in same level scope. after than you can use it in your `insert` query.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: What actual you want?? try this `if($insert == 1)` after your insert query instead of `if($insert) {`

Comment: how can i do this properly?????

Comment: is there any one who can help me for this task...........???

Comment: any one is there.....???